# Intercepting global functions with Valgrind on Linux using g++

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, valgrind, interception

I'm trying to intercept a function with Valgrind, according to [their example](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.wrapping).

I am able to do the interception of global function when building with gcc, however when I compile the same code with g++, interception doesn't work.

Is there anything special in the compiler flags I should specify?

Here's my sample app:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "valgrind.h"

__attribute__ ((noinline))
void foo()
{
    printf("inside foo\n");
}

void I_WRAP_SONAME_FNNAME_ZU(NONE,foo)()
{
   OrigFn fn;
   VALGRIND_GET_ORIG_FN(fn);
   printf("*** Before foo()\n");
   CALL_FN_v_v(fn);
   printf("*** After foo()\n");
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with GCC, the output is:

> `*** Before foo()`
>   `inside foo`
>   `*** After foo()`

However when compiled with g++, the output is simply

> inside foo

Comment: On my system, when compiling with C++, I get an object name of `_Z3foov` for the function. (C++ [mangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) C names.) (Use `readelf -s file` to dump the symbol table.) *But*, I couldn't get the correct result by simply replacing `foo` with `_Z3foov` in my program. So I'm very confused. Thanks for showing me this, though. :)

Comment: Have you tried `extern "C"`-ing the function wrapper? There may be an issue because the `I_WRAP_SONAME_FNNAME_ZU` function name is being mangled.

Answer (score 2):

G++ does a name mangling for function without `extern "C"`. So you should to find a mangled name (e.g. with `nm object`) and use it in your valgrind code. Or you can rewrite your target program to use an `extern "C"` function.